# Blurry Printing from Google Chrome to thermal printer

Tags: printing, google-chrome-app, thermal-printer, point-of-sale

I am using google chrome for POS, my problem when i print the receipt from the browser the printing very blurry and bad quality.
Any idea how to fix this.
I am using ZYWELL, Thermal Receipt.

Printing from any another app is okay, But printing from browsers is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I couldn't solve it, I used Firefox and it worked better

Edit:

```
html{
  color:black;
}
```

Works well